# Phantomjs 'killed' on run in ubuntu 12.04 not in windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, crash, phantomjs, screenshot

I am running a very simple script through phantomjs to get screenshot of webpage with bing maps.

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('workfileNew.html', function() {
    page.render('output.jpg');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

It runs fine in windows but I get a 'Killed' in ubuntu. In both OS the version is 1.9.7.

If I replace `workFileNew.html` with `www.google.com` then it works fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried with a file path: `file:///home/user/path/workfileNew.html`?

Comment: I could have tried this but upgrading the memory fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem. It was a lack of memory on the VPS i am renting. Previously it was 256 MB ram. When I upgraded the ram to 1 GB it worked fine. I suppose could also have decreased the resolution of the image as well.